# Creating a table using C# and CSV file

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a table in C# Visual Studio 2017.I'm kind of green when it comes to using Visual Studio.

I plan to use a CSV. file

[CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEElg.png)

I want the table to look like so:

firstName + secondName and amount of money donated by the person.

I'm trying to make it simple out of the stuff we have used in class

At the end, I want to add the numbers together so that I get the sum of all those numbers in the notepad document, also I would like to display the person that has the biggest number beside their name with the number, and at the end just to display all people first name + second name + number **but only people who have 150 or above beside their name**

### Edit

Here is a simple layout I made before, but I'm struggling with combining 2 separate names/words together + numbers.

[Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsJRT.png)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string fileIn = "C:/quiz-results.csv";//reads in the file from the H drive
        if (File.Exists(fileIn))
        {
            //filefound
            string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileIn);
            string[] names = new string[allLines.Length];// creates array for the data that is going to be used in this program
            int[] scores = new int[allLines.Length];

            string[] quizResults = new string[allLines.Length];//array to store the final result



            for (int i = 0; i < allLines.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] lineSpilt = allLines[i].Split(',');
                names[i] = lineSpilt[0];
                scores[i] = Convert.ToInt32(lineSpilt[1]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++)//loops through the whole array scores
            {
                //compute result
                quizResults[i] = ComputeResult(scores[i]);
            }

            // output to console
            OutputResultsToConsole(names, quizResults);
            // find best score
            int bestScore = GetBestScore(scores);
            Console.WriteLine("the best overall score was:{0}", bestScore);
            //find worst score
            int worstScore = GetWorstSCore(scores);
            Console.WriteLine("the worst overall score was:{0}", worstScore);





            //find worst score index and name
            int worstScoreIndex = GetWorstSCoreIndex(scores);
            Console.WriteLine("the worst overall score was:{0} ({1})", scores[worstScoreIndex], names[worstScoreIndex]);



            //number of passes
            int numberOfPasses = GetNumberOfPasses(quizResults);
            Console.WriteLine("the number of passes were: {0}", numberOfPasses);
            //number of fails
            int numberOfFails = GetNumberOfFails(quizResults);
            Console.WriteLine("the number of fails were: {0}", numberOfFails);
            // get average score
            int averageScore = ComputeAverageOverallScore(scores);
            Console.WriteLine("the average quiz score was : {0}", averageScore);


            // scored less than 12
            Console.WriteLine("Scored less than 12");
            for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++)
            {
                if (scores[i] < 12)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", names[i], scores[i]);
                }
            }

            // output to txt file
            string fileOut = "E:/results-2016-final.txt";
            OutputResultsToTxtFile(fileOut, names, quizResults, bestScore, worstScore, numberOfPasses, numberOfFails, averageScore);


        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    private static void OutputResultsToTxtFile(string fileOut, string[] names, string[] quizResults, int bestScore, int worstScore, int numberOfPasses, int numberOfFails, int averageScore)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("Results 2016 - Final");
        // individaul restults
        for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.AppendLine($"{names[i],-20}: {quizResults[i]}");
        }
        // summary data // all display on the text file
        sb.AppendLine();
        sb.AppendLine("Summary Data");
        sb.AppendLine($"Highest Score: {bestScore}");
        sb.AppendLine($"Lowest Score : {worstScore}");
        sb.AppendLine($"Number Of Passes : {numberOfPasses}");
        sb.AppendLine($"Number Of Fails : {numberOfFails}");
        sb.AppendLine($"Average Score : {averageScore}");
        sb.AppendLine("----------------- END OF FILE ----------------");
        // write data to file
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileOut))
        {
            sw.Write(sb);


        }
    }


    private static int ComputeAverageOverallScore(int[] scores)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++)//lopping through the lenght of the array
        {
            sum += scores[i];//+= means add the two values to sum // i++ is the same as i+=1 or i+1
        }
        int average = sum / scores.Length;
        return average;
    }




    private static int GetNumberOfFails(string[] quizResults)
    {
        int count = 0;// declaring a variable of the type int and asigns it the value of 0

        foreach (string i in quizResults)// loops through the whole array looking for strings
        {
            if (i == "fail")
            {
                count++;//add one to count
            }
        }
        return count;// returns the count value
    }


    private static int GetNumberOfPasses(string[] quizResults)
    {
        int count = 0;// declaring a variable of the type int and asigns it the value of 0

        foreach (string i in quizResults)// loops through the whole array looking for strings
        {
            if (i == "pass")
            {
                count++;//add one to count
            }
        }
        return count;// returns the count value
    }


    private static int GetWorstSCore(int[] scores)
    {
        int worstScore = scores[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < scores.Length; i++)
        {
            if (scores[i] < worstScore)
            {
                worstScore = scores[i];
            }
        }

        return worstScore;
    }


    private static int GetWorstSCoreIndex(int[] scores)//name
    {
        int index = 0;
        int worstScore = scores[index];

        for (int i = 1; i < scores.Length; i++)
        {
            if (scores[i] < worstScore)
            {
                worstScore = scores[i];
                index = i;
            }
        }

        return index;
    }

    private static int GetBestScore(int[] scores)
    {
        int bestScore = scores[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < scores.Length; i++)
        {
            if (scores[i] > bestScore)
            {
                bestScore = scores[i];
            }
        }

        return bestScore;
    }

    private static string ComputeResult(int score)// finds out of the student has passed
    {
        if (score >= PASS_MARK)
        {
            return "pass";
        }
        else
        {
            return "fail";
        }



    }

    private static void OutputResultsToConsole(string[] names, string[] quizResults)// output the names and there reults to the console
    {
        Console.WriteLine("results 2016");
        for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-12} {1} ", names[i], quizResults[i]);

        }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: What language do you plan to use? Visual Studio is just an editor, and is capable of working with several languages. VB.net? C#? etc.

Comment: Note that is a very broad, and it may be closed as a result. If you can make an initial start on this and show that in the question, that really does help encourage readers to answer (effort begets effort!).

Comment: Hi we would be using C# I'm about to make a start on it @halfer, i just had to pick up the stuff from college the day.

Comment: Take another screenshot, this time crop out 99% of the image, which is just whitespace, so we can actually see what you want us to look at.\

Comment: Create a table in what buddy. It could be a web app, windows forms, what are you looking for???

Comment: Hey all, I've cropped the images, and fixed couple of errors, can anyone lead me/show me the code of how table like this would be done using the CSV file i've put in the description?

Comment: Please do not post images of, or links to, your code or data. We can't copy or paste them, the SO search can't search them, and when your link expires your question will not make any sense. Your “CSV” file is not comma-separated, and [`.Split(',')`](http://www.secretgeek.net/csv_trouble) won't parse one anyway.